# Postman scripting: cannot save environment variable via test script

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a couple of requests as part of my collection and wanted to set an environment variable with a value from the JSON response output.

This variable is not defined in the **Manage Environments** section.

Is it mandatory that I would have to first declare the environment variable under **Manage Environments** section?

If I do declare it in the **Manage Environments** section, then it is working^

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('sessionId', jsonData.sessionId);
```

My other question is I'm at loss on why this is passing?

I have the following code snippet in one of my requests:

```
{
    "sessionid": "15c3f72e-788f-423f-b1cc-5dca503ae859",
    "expires": "2019-02-17T20:57:20.24234222-08:00",
    "cookievalue": "MySession"
}

pm.test("Check if session id is returned"), function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("sessionid2");
}
```

I'm surprised by why this is working?

It should fail since I don't have `sessionid2` in the JSON response.

I tried all other ways including `pm.response.json()` and nothing works.

Btw, how do I test to see if the key exists in the JSON response and not necessarily to check the value since the session id value may change each time?

Other than the docs, can somebody point me to a good resource to learn more about Postman scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question regarding saving an environment variable, you would need to create an environment file first, in order for it to know *where* to save the variable. You could use the `pm.globals.set()` function instead if you didn't want to create a file first.

For the second question, it looks like your `test` syntax is wrong as you've closed off the test by adding the extra `)` after the test name.

Using something like this instead should work:

```
pm.test("Check if session id is returned", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.include.key("sessionid");
})
```

Comment: thanks @danny. I'm not seeing an option to create a environment file from within Postman. Please advise. Also, can you please refer to any other useful blogs other than the docs for getting to know more about Postman and possibly Newman?

Comment: Have you looked at the Postman documentation, YouTube channel...google etc. Its a widely used tool so there is a wealth of information out there. I have a github repo we different postman related things if you want yo check that out too.

Comment: Awesome. Can you let me know the github url?